# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: linkCollectionFactory

Tags: magento2

getting error while add to cart magento 2.4.2

```
    1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: linkCollectionFactory in 
/var/www/html/242/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Observer/IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver.php on line 53
```

Please help me out with this error

Comment: Have you created any observer or override this file in your module ? Any other module installed after which you were getting this error ? Please provide full error traceback to identify it more.